# How to split a node value which has xml as string in xslt

Tags: xslt

We have a requirement where we are getting an XML payload in form of String for one node and we need to expand this XML and pass the XML node values to destination XSD columns.

For example Input XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/2012/SCEM">
    <TRXKEY>0x0000013</TRXKEY>
    <EVENTNAME>SalesOrder</EVENTNAME>
    <ACCEPTEDQUANTITY>0</ACCEPTEDQUANTITY>
    <ORDEREDQUANTITY>0</ORDEREDQUANTITY>
    <SOLORGID>0</SOLORGID>
    <LHORDERHOLDIDRELEASED>0</LHORDERHOLDIDRELEASED>
    <ORDEREDQUANTITYUOM>0</ORDEREDQUANTITYUOM>
    <UNITSELLINGPRICE>0</UNITSELLINGPRICE>
    <ORDERTYPE>&lt;Val lang='AR'&gt;OrderTypeARARARAR&lt;/Val&gt;
                    &lt;Val lang='KO'&gt;OrderTypeKOKOKOKO&lt;/Val&gt;
                    &lt;Val lang='US'&gt;OrderTypeUSUSUUS&lt;/Val&gt;
                   </ORDERTYPE>
</Transaction>
```

Output XML

```
<Transaction1 xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/2012/SCEM">
    <TRXKEY>0x0000013</TRXKEY>
    <EVENTNAME>SalesOrder</EVENTNAME>
    <ACCEPTEDQUANTITY>0</ACCEPTEDQUANTITY>
    <ORDEREDQUANTITY>0</ORDEREDQUANTITY>
    <SOLORGID>0</SOLORGID>
    <LHORDERHOLDIDRELEASED>0</LHORDERHOLDIDRELEASED>
    <ORDEREDQUANTITYUOM>0</ORDEREDQUANTITYUOM>
    <UNITSELLINGPRICE>0</UNITSELLINGPRICE>
    <ORDERTYPE_AR>OrderTypeARARARAR</ORDERTYPE_AR>
    <ORDERTYPE_US>OrderTypeUSUSUUS</ORDERTYPE_US>
    <ORDERTYPE_KO>OrderTypeKOKOKOKO</ORDERTYPE_KO>
</Transaction>
```

We need to loop through the ORDERTYPE node XML string. Depending on the 'Val lang=' value we need to pass this node value to output XSD ORDERTYPE_$lang value column.

How can I loop through this XML string for these 2 different values and pass it to the corresponding output XML column?

I was thinking of using split but it is not helping much.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? To parse XML you need an extension function like Saxon 9.5 provides or you need to use an XSLT 3.0 processor and the 3.0 function http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-xpath-functions-30-20130521/#func-parse-xml. Or in the case of your sample even http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-xpath-functions-30-20130521/#func-parse-xml-fragment.

Comment: I want to achieve this in stylesheet version="1.0"

Comment: If you want to use an XSLT 1.0 processor then check whether it provides an extension function that parses a string with XML into nodes or whether the processor allows you to implement such an extension function. Another option with XSLT 1.0 would be to write two stylesheets where the first use e.g. `<xsl:template match="ORDERTYPE"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` and the second then processes the serialized result of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Martin,

```
I have come up with below code which resolved my issue.

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
            xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
            xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction"
            xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
            xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
            xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:med="http://schemas.oracle.com/mediator/xpath"
            xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath"
            xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
            xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/KeyStore/emsProjXslt/BPELProcess1"
            xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk"
            xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
            xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/2012/SCEM"
            xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
            xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator"
            xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl client ns2 plnk xsd wsdl bpws xp20 mhdr bpel oraext dvm hwf med ids bpm xdk xref ora socket ldap">
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns2:Transaction>

          <ns2:TRXKEY>
            <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:Transaction/ns2:TRXKEY"/>
          </ns2:TRXKEY>
            <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Parameters">
            <xsl:with-param name="sourceNodes"
                            select='substring-after(/ns2:Transaction/ns2:ORDERTYPE,"Val lang=")'/>
          </xsl:call-template>

        </ns2:Transaction>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template name="for.loop.Parameters">
        <xsl:param name="sourceNodes"/>
        <xsl:variable name="temp">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($sourceNodes) > '0'">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($sourceNodes,'&lt;/Val>')"/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Expression" select="substring-after($temp, '>')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Expression1" select="substring-before($temp, '>')"/>

        <xsl:if test="contains($Expression1,'AR')">
          <ns2:ORDERTYPE_AR>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Expression"/>
          </ns2:ORDERTYPE_AR>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($Expression,'US')">
          <ns2:ORDERTYPE_US>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Expression"/>
          </ns2:ORDERTYPE_US>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($Expression,'KO')">
          <ns2:ORDERTYPE_KO>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Expression"/>
          </ns2:ORDERTYPE_KO>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="test">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($sourceNodes,'/Val>')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($test) > 1 ">
          <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Parameters">
            <xsl:with-param name="sourceNodes">
              <xsl:value-of select='substring-after($test,"Val lang=")'/>
            </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```